# Generate "Next Number" and add it to char*

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I've tried to create a simple program that would allow me to increment a current integer and replace the last "n characters" in a char*.

However, no matter what I do, it simply outputs the same thing all over.

e.g Index = 1

Output: 
XX201701
XX201702
XX201703
XX201704
...
XX201710

Could someone possibly tell me what am I doing wrong here?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int index = 1;
char* GenerateNext()
{
    char* def = new char[9];
    char buffer[9];

    int counter = 0;
    int temp = index;

    while (temp != 0)
    {
        temp /= 10;
        counter++;
    }

    strncpy_s(def, 9, "XX160000", 8 - counter); 
    _itoa_s(counter, buffer, 9, 10);
    strcat_s(def, 9, buffer);

    index++;
    return def;
}

int main() 
{
    char* generated = GenerateNext();
    char* generated2 = GenerateNext();

    cout << generated << endl << generated2 << endl;

    delete[] generated;
    delete[] generated2;

    generated = nullptr; 
    generated2 = nullptr;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: What you are doing wrong? Using new and c-strings. Forget about explicit new and char-pointers for managing strings. Simply use std::string. And throw away system("pause");. There is cin.get();

Comment: The expected result would be as it was mentioned above: XX201701, XX201702, XX201703, XX201704, ... XX201710

Comment: @TheTechel Well, I am "practicing" (turns out it's not even practice if I can't figure it out anymore) char* stuff, so I "gotta" use that method.

Comment: don't practice that 'Char*'-stuff, as you will never need this. This is rather C-ish. In general, pointers are not used very often in C++ compared to C. To solve your problem, use the debugger.

Comment: Use std::string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to print `index` instead of a `counter`:

```
_itoa_s(index, buffer, 9, 10);
```

Because value of `counter` will be 1 for 1..9 `index` so output string will remain the same.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. I don't know why, but for some reason, I had mischecked the "int counter = 0;" and forgot that it will be reset to 0 every time the function gets called. Thanks for the help.